# Using "update" as noun

Tags: phrase-meaning

I wrote this sentence

> Updates to the context variables are shown below this panel.

It is supposed to means something like

> Fields show the values specified to update the context variables

Does that convey this?

Comment: To me it sounds that "below this panel" the user can see *to what* the variables *have already been* updated.  But it doesn't really come from the meaning of "update", more of the feeling I get.

Comment: To get round the ambiguity @Victor refers to, you could call them ***pending** updates* if the variables haven't *yet* been updated. (If they *have*, obviously you're simply showing the current values of the variables - equivalent to *the most recent update/change*.)

Comment: I want to say they are the values we entered to update somethings (to change the variables, these are the values), then you mean it doesn't convey that.

Comment: Your first sentence is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I read that sentence I would expect that the panel below would be a list of recent updates to the variables. It would be a similar usage to phrases like *recent changes* or *latest news*. As pointed out in the comments if they have not yet been implemented then they are only planned updates.